# Keeping Buttons Active State in Submenu

Tags: css, wordpress-theming

On rolling over a submenu option i want to keep the colour of the button in an active state

http://www.milknhny.co.uk/SofiaWork/

```
ul.headermenu ul ul li a:hover
```

the above appears to not work, can someone advise?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have to use JavaScript to keep that state of style in tact. What you do is bind listeners to the menu ul's and keep the coloring as is when hovering it's (sub-)children.

CSS4 (not safe to use yet) has a parent selector;

```
ul ul! < li:hover {

}
```

Comment: any idea where i can find this js?? Thanks allendar